# ¿Cómo puede decirse "consumerization" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

La [**consumerización**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumerizaci%C3%B3n) (ahí es nada) es una situación que se produce actualmente con las tecnologías emergentes, que son adoptadas primero por el mercado, generalmente gente joven que ha crecido en un mundo tecnológico y está menos inclinada a diferenciar entre la tecnología corporativa y la personal, y esperan poder usar esa tecnología en el trabajo. Se llega a producir un impacto en los departamentos de informática de las grandes empresas, al no poder controlar ni gestionar las nuevas tecnologías que ni siquiera han suministrado.

Ya se produjo un caso similar en los años 80 del siglo pasado, al llegar a las empresas egresados universitarios que habían utilizado computadores personales en la universidad y, de alguna manera, obligaron a su introducción en las empresas que no los tenían y ni sabían que era eso.

¿Hay alguna traducción al castellano para esta palabra?

Comment: ¿Qué has considerado, y cuáles fuentes has probado?  Eché un ojo a linguee.com y encontré una posibilidad: *The EESC warns that a common approach could result in an unwanted "consumerisation" of public health, confusing the concepts of "user" and "consumer" and lumping them together as common aspects of "citizenship".*

Comment: No he encontrado nada que me de una traducción más allá de **consumerización**. Puse una consulta en el foro TIC del Centro Virtual Cervantes, pero no he recibido respuestas, imagino que nadie tiene una idea clara de como 'atacar' este neologismo en castellano.

Answer (score 1):

El artículo de Wikipedia utiliza dos términos: "consumerización" y "consumidorización".

Centrémonos en el segundo de ellos. Si lo separamos en elementos, tenemos que proviene de `consumidor` + `-izar` + `-ación`. Por pasos:

1. **Se toma el sustantivo [consumidor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ASyDmz0)**.
2. Al sustantivo anterior, **se le aplica el sufijo [-izar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MFIHFG2)** para formar el verbo "**consumidorizar**", significando "convertir en consumidor".
3. Al verbo anterior, **se le aplica el sufijo [-ación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9I27Gyi)** para formar el sustantivo "**consumidorización**", significando "acción y efecto de consumidorizar (esto es, de convertir en consumidor).

**Esta transformación es correcta**, y es además exactamente la misma que se ha aplicado en inglés al tomar el sustantivo [*consumer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consumer) y aplicarle los sufijos [*-ize*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ize) y [*-ation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ation), con idéntica función a sus equivalentes españoles.

Fijémonos ahora en el primero, "**consumerización**". Si intentamos separar ese palabro en raíz y sufijos, tendríamos `consumer` + `-izar` + `-ación`, lo cual **no es correcto** puesto que "consumer" no existe en español. Este palabro se limita a "adaptar" el inglés *consumerization*, sustituyendo la terminación *-ization* por "-ización", la grafía española habitual para palabras similares.

Por tanto, **en español lo gramaticalmente correcto sería "consumidorización"**, no *consumerización*.

Esto no impide que, en un futuro, el DLE pueda incluir la palabra *consumerización* como anglicismo si se extiende su uso.

Comment: Gracias @walen es la primera respuesta que obtengo desde que llevo preguntando por este neologismo. La verdad es que aunque sea una construcción correcta en español, "consumidorizar" no es que suene muy bien, más parece un trabalenguas.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar en el documento 'International Qualifications Board for Business Analysis' versión 1.0 del año 2011 el término 'user innovation', que traducido sería: Mejora realizada por los usuarios finales, como individuos o grupos. El creador de la innovación es el usuario final que desarrolla o perfecciona los productos y servicios adquiridos en el lugar de uso.